# how to zoom stage to rectangle area in as3 (Action Scripts 3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

how to zoom stage to rectangle area in as3 (Action Scripts 3)?

i have a text, when mouse over the ever word, color changed.
now, when click the word i need to zoom to this word and hide the other word?

Comment: What did you try? What's your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

اینه که زوم کنه و بقیه کلمات از کادر بره بیرون درسته؟  hide other words:.سلام.منظورت از

translate:
do you mean "hide other words", zoom to send other words out of stage?

```
var zoomAmount:Number=3;//مقدار زوم  , zoom amount
var wordX:number=???;// موقعیت طولی نقطه ی بالا-چپ کلمه ی مورد نظر ,x of zooming word
var wordY:number=???;// موقعیت ارتفاعی نقطه ی بالا-چپ کلمه ی مورد نظر ,y of zooming word


txt.addEventListener("click",zoom);


function zoom(e:MouseEvent=null){
     this.x=-wordX;
     this.y=-wordY;
     this.scaleX=this.scaleY=zoomAmount;
```

امیدوارم این پست کمک کنه☺

Comment: سلام، متاسفانه جواب نداد . من روی یک فایل تست کار میکنم که اینه

Comment: چرا کار نکرد؟مشکلش چیه؟

Comment: در حالت معمولی کار میکنه البته نمیشه دقیقا گفت که زوم باید چقدر باشه---اما من چون داخل یه اسپریت استفاده میکنم درست کار نمیکنه، میاره وسط های صفحه

Comment: اولا اسکیل هارو جا انداختی. دوما یکم باید رو ایکس و وایش کار کنی .جای درست برن

Answer (score 0):

put your text inside movieclip and give the movieclip instance name yourWord.

```
  yourWord.addEventListner(MouseEvent.CLICK,onCLICK);
    function on CLICK(e:MouseEvent){
    yourWord.xScale = yourWord.yScale = 2;
    }
```

Note:
If you want some easing animtion then you can use tweenlite library or flash inbuilt tweener methods.